# Check if no command line arguments and STDIN is empty

Tags: bash, shell-script

How to check, in a Bash script, that no command line arguments or STDIN was provided ?

I mean if I run:

```
#> ./myscript.sh
... Show message "No data provided..." and exit
```

Or:

```
#> ./myscript.sh filename.txt
... Read from filename.txt
```

Or:

```
#> ./myscript.sh < filename.txt**
... Read from STDIN
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Does this fit your requirements ?

```
#!/bin/sh

if test -n "$1"; then
    echo "Read from $1";
elif test ! -t 0; then
    echo "Read from stdin"
else
    echo "No data provided..."
fi
```

The major tricks are as follow:

- Detecting that you have an argument is done through the `test -n $1` which is checking if a first argument exists.
- Then, checking if `stdin` is not open on the terminal (because it is piped to a file) is done with `test ! -t 0` (check if the file descriptor zero (aka `stdin`) is not open).
- And, finally, everything else fall in the last case (`No data provided...`).

Comment: Yes, sorry for my erroneous edit. I misread your code and thought for a while that you were using `read` with a timeout...

Comment: No problem! But, my code works with POSIX shell (I tried it before sending, just to be sure). :-)

Comment: Would it work with stdin from a pipe though? Hmmm... probably. But it would fail if stdin had been explicitly closed... The -t test is true if the fd is open and associated with a terminal. If its false, either its closed or not associated with a terminal.

Comment: @Kusalananda: You are totally right! If `stdin` has been closed for some other reason, it will wrongly deduce that it reads from a file given on `stdin`. But, I do not see how to do better than that... If you can come with a better solution, I would be delighted to see it!

Comment: @perror I don't think it matters too much as `read` would return (with a "bad filediscriptor" error) immediately, and that could be handled as a data error, i.e. the data was _supposed_ to come from standard input, but there was something wrong with it.

Comment: I wrote https://github.com/NightMachinary/possiblycat to add a timeout to the `test ! -t 0` case. It works more reliably that way.

Comment: While OP accepted this - it does not answer the question title, i.e. it checks for STDIN being a terminal.

Answer (score 5):

I searched far and wide to no avail, and finally managed to put this together through much trial and error.  It has worked flawlessly for me in numerous use-cases ever since.

```
#!/bin/bash
### LayinPipe.sh
## Recreate "${@}" as "${Args[@]}"; appending piped input.
## Offers usable positional parameters regardless of where the input came from.
##
## You could choose to create the array with "${@}" instead following
##  any piped arguments by simply swapping the order
##   of the following two 'if' statements.

# First, check for normal positional parameters.
if [[ ${@} ]]; then
    while read line; do
        Args[${#Args[@]}]="${line}"
    done < <(printf '%s\n' "${@}")
fi

# Then, check for piped input.
if [[ ! -t 0 ]]; then
    while read line; do
        Args[${#Args[@]}]="${line}"
    done < <(cat -)
fi

# Behold the glory.
for ((a=0;a<${#Args[@]};a++)); do
    echo "${a}: ${Args[a]}"
done
```

- Example:   (knowing full well that using output of 'ls' as input is discouraged in order to show the flexibility of this solution.)

```
$ ls
: TestFile.txt 'Filename with spaces'

$ ls -1 | LayinPipe.sh "$(ls -1)"
> 0: Filename with spaces
> 1: TestFile.txt 
> 2: Filename with spaces
> 3: TestFile.txt 

$ LayinPipe.sh "$(ls -1)"
> 0: Filename with spaces
> 1: TestFile.txt 

$ ls -1 | LayinPipe.sh
> 0: Filename with spaces
> 1: TestFile.txt
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Spent quite a bit of time before finding your answer.

Comment: found an edge case. if you `printf "foo" | LayInPipe.sh` you'll get no output. Requires a trailing newline to work.

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED] in bash shell ...

... read -t 0 : see 'help read'

```
$ function read_if_stdin_not_empty {
if read -t 0 ; then
  while read ; do
    echo "stdin receive : $REPLY"
    read_if_stdin_not_empty
  done
else 
  echo "stdin is empty .."
fi
}

# TESTs:

$ read_if_stdin_not_empty
stdin is empty ..

$ echo '123' | read_if_stdin_not_empty
stdin receive : 123

$s='123                        
456'
$ echo "$s" | read_if_stdin_not_empty
stdin receive : 123
stdin receive : 456
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose a function that synthesizes the previous very interesting answers:

File test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
function init_STDIN() {
  ## Version 1.0.0
  ## Creates the global variable array indexed STDIN
  ## which contains the possible lines sent in the
  ## file descriptor /dev/stdin of the script
  declare -ga STDIN
  read -t0 || return 1
  while read LINE; do
    STDIN[${#STDIN[@]}]="$LINE"
  done < <(cat -)
  test ${#STDIN[@]} -ne 0
}

if init_STDIN; then
  echo "Feed provided on /dev/stdin. Processing..."
  echo "For this example, /dev/stdin is:"
  for ((I=0; I<${#STDIN[@]}; I++)); do
    echo ${STDIN[$I]}
  done
else
  echo "Working without any feed on /dev/stdin..."
fi

echo
echo "For this example, the ${#@} parameter(s) provided on the command line is(are) :"
echo $@
```

TESTS:

```
$ ./test.sh some args ...
Working without any feed on /dev/stdin...

For this example, the 3 parameter(s) provided on the command line is(are) :
some args ...


$ seq 1 10 | sed 's/ /\n/g' | ./test.sh some args ...
Feed provided on /dev/stdin. Processing...
For this example, /dev/stdin is:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

For this example, the 3 parameter(s) provided on the command line is(are) :
some args ...


$ seq 1 10 | sed 's/ /\n/g' | (exec 0<&-; ./test.sh some args ...)
Working without any feed on /dev/stdin...

For this example, the 3 parameter(s) provided on the command line is(are) :
some args ...
```