# how to add additional command-line usage scenarios to script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, scripting

how can one make this script work with both input usage scenarios below?

```
#1    ./script.sh
#2    ./script.sh input.file
```

contents of `script.sh`

`for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4`

scenario `#1` is the only one working right now because the file contents above specifically allow one to run `script.sh` within a directory where all `.mp4` files will be targeted.

is it possible to also target an individual file rather than the whole directory, however still keep the other usage scenario `#1` available at all times to use.

UPDATE: I do not see how this is related the the question he is commenting about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if no command line arguments and STDIN is empty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484630/check-if-no-command-line-arguments-and-stdin-is-empty)

Comment: @Anonymous The question is slightly different, but the solution is almost identical.

Comment: Ahh, I am trying to apply that but I don't see it. I don't think I am experienced enough at this yet.

Comment: You want two cases: one with arguments given, one without - that's what's in the duplicate (which asks for an additional case, which you can ignore). You gain experience by trying out things.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the argument as the path. You can use a simple trick: `/path/to/dir/./` is the same as `/path/to/dir/` since `./` means 'the current directory. So for this simple case, you could just do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$1"./*.mp4; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; 
done
```

And then run the script either like this:

```
cd /path/to/mp4; /path/to/script.sh
```

Or like this (the final slash is essential):

```
/path/to/script.sh /path/to/mp4/
```

---

The general way of doing this is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Assign the 1st argument to the variable "target"
target=$1
## If $target has no value (if $1 was empty), set it to "."
target=${target:="."}

for i in "$target"/*.mp4; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; 
done
```

The variable isn't actually needed, you can just do:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in ${1-.}/*.mp4; do 
    echo ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; 
done
```

Or:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  target="."
else
  target="$1"
fi

for i in "$target"/*.mp4; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; 
done
```

Comment: `"$1"/./*.mp4` would default to the root directory if `$1` is empty, not the current dir. And it doesn't need a trailing slash, but `"$1"./*.mp4` would. `${var:=.}` should be [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), but `target=${target:="."}` seems a bit redundant with essentially a double assignment. I think just `"${1-.}"/*.mp4` should do if one wants to be brief...

Comment: @ilkkachu argh, yes, of course. I'd even seen that and fixed it in the version I was using for testing but forgot to copy it to the answer! Thanks.  And you're quite right about `${1-.}`, for some reason that hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: (actually, if `$1` is `/`, then `"${1-.}"/*.mp4`, expands to `//*.mp4` which [is allowed to be different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/170373) from just `/*.mp4`, but it probably isn't on the most common systems. (I know I've seen a question about the systems where that applies somewhere on the site.) So yeah, maybe the conditional is better.)